# Bash wrapper for connmanctl with autocompletion

Tags: bash, sed, awk, autocomplete

So the idea came from the fact that

- `connmanctl` only completes filenames/directories when used non-interactively,
- whereas when used interactively (executing `connmanctl` without arguments an interactive shell is started), it does support autocompletion, but when it comes to completing services (wifi networks, ethernet connections, bluetooth devices, ...) it completes the *service path* (as it is referred to in `man connmanctl`, instead of the name of the connection. In other words, if a line of `connmanctl services` is the following

  ```
  myHomeWifi            wifi_79829c350ea0_41542d233241335454_managed_psk
  ```

  then `connmanctl connect wifi<Tab>` will complete the second string, whereas I would like `connmanctl connect myH<Tab>` to complete the first.

If there is an in-`connmanctl` solution, feel free to point me to that, but I took this unpleasant feature of `connmanctl` as a chance to write a wrapper for it which also handles autocompletion.

The wrapper itself is just this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A map
eval "$(command connmanctl services | \
  awk 'NF > 1 { print "map["$(NF - 1)"]="$NF; next }
              { print "map["$NF"]="$NF }')"
i=0
declare -a args
for arg in "$@"; do
  [[ "${map[$arg]}" ]] && args[i++]="${map[$arg]}" || args[i++]="$arg"
done
command connmanctl "${args[@]}"
```

Essentially it does the following:

- It should be called with the same arguments you would call `connmanctl`.
- Builds an associative array out of `connmanctl services`'s output,
- loops on the command line arguments and substitutes the `wifi_*`-like string if the other string matched (I guess this is a weak point, in the case a service is named, for instance, `connect`),
- and then forwards the modified list of arguments to `connmanctl`.

The autocompletion is handled by the following script, where the heredoc is handmade by exploring how `connmanctl` completes.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main='ConnMan'

_ConnMan_completions()
{
  mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(compgen -W "$(__compListGen "${COMP_WORDS[@]}")" -- "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}")
}

__compListGen() {
  __tree | __subTree "$@" | __expandServices | __dropChildren
}

__subTree() {
  # forward in to out if no args
  (( $# == 0 )) && tee && return

  # remove the last parameter if it's being completed
  (( $# == COMP_CWORD + 1 )) && set -- "${@:1:$(($# - 1))}"

  # process first entry and pipe recursively
  one=$1
  shift
  __getNode "$one" < /dev/stdin | __subTree "$@"
}

__getNode() {
  # all services match a common string in the heredoc
  [[ "$(command connmanctl services)" =~ $1 ]] && set -- '@services'
  # if first line matching $1 is followed by @repeat line,
  # print only these two; if not, print only lines beginning
  # with tab, up to the next line not beginning with tab
  sed -E '/(^| )'"$1"'( |$)/,/^[^\t]/{
            /^\t@repeat$/{H;x;p;Q}
            h
            /^\t/s/\t//p
          }
          d' /dev/stdin
}

__expandServices() {
  input=$(< /dev/stdin)
  case "$input" in
    [^@]* )
      echo "$input"
      ;;
    @services* )
      command connmanctl services | \
        sed -E 's/^[^ ]* *([^ ].*[^ ])  *[^ ]*$/\1/
                s/^ *//'
      ;;
    # the default case is not needed, as this case
    # statement is tightly bounded to the heredoc below
  esac
}

__dropChildren() {
  sed '/^\t/d' /dev/stdin
}

__tree() {
  # The heredoc below hardcodes connmanctl's completion tree.
  # The special entry @services refers to when connmanctl
  # completes with the available services, whereas the
  # entry @repeat refers to when connmanctl keeps giving
  # the same alternative completions as the for the last
  # word.
  cat <<EOF
$main
    agent
        on
        off
    clock
    config
        @services
            autoconnect domains ipv4 ipv6 mdns nameservers proxy remove timeservers
                @repeat
    connect
        @services
    disable
        ethernet
        offline
        wifi
    disconnect
        @services
    enable
        ethernet
        offline
        wifi
    exit
    help
    monitor
        manager
            on
            off
        services
            on
            off
        tech
            on
            off
        vpnconnection
            on
            off
        vpnmanager
            on
            off
    move-after
        @services
    move-before
        @services
    peer_service
    peers
    quit
    scan
        ethernet
        wifi
    services
        @services
    session
        bearers ctxid ifname srciprule type
            @repeat
    state
    technologies
    tether
        ethernet
            on
            off
        wifi
            on
            off
    tethering_clients
    vpnagent
        on
        off
    vpnconnections
EOF
}

complete -o default -F _ConnMan_completions $main
```